What does the word 歪む mean in this context?
I was watching a Japanese YouTuber play through Paper Mario the thousand year door, which has a trans character in the Japanese version that’s not trans in the international version. When she got to the part where that character becomes a member of your party, she said:

こんなの歪むわ！こんなの子供の頃にやったら歪むわ。しかもさ、結構序盤のうちにビビアン(キャラクターの名前) が男だってわかってるじゃん。わかった上でさ、このビビアンが男だと知らずに好意を抱いちゃったら後でがっかりしたりとか、でもあの時は女だと思ってたし言い訳できるじゃん。でも、このペーパーマリオRPGは一味違います。もうステージ2の時点でビビアンは男だということを事前に知らせた上でこの可愛さをぶつけてきて我々を歪ませにきています、真正面からね

It says the definition of 歪む means to distort, but it also says one of its meanings is to be perverted? I’m kind of confused on what it means and what she’s talking about when she’s using it. Can anyone explain to me what she’s saying and what the word means in this context?

In these situations, it's usually better to look up a Japanese definition. Here's one that might be useful for this context, I don't see what else it could be: 心や行いなどが正しくなくなる。

The speaker basically says that the players might develop weird tendencies due to how cute the character is in the game, somewhat jokingly.
性格が歪む is a common collocation for developing weird [personality] tendencies. It looks like 性癖が歪む is used in a similar manner for weird sexual preferences. The -が part can be deduced from the context when omitted (and if you don't know the larger context, it can be hard to understand what is distorted).
"Perversion" might be too a strong word, but with 歪む the speaker does imply it would be an unhealthy development, if jokingly.
